# Proving that $f(x) = (1-\cos x)\sin\frac1x$ is equally continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, proof-writing

When dealing with a proof that a given function is a equally continuous function, and the function involves trigonometry, I find it hard if not impossible to prove it via the definition of an equally continuous function. I am looking for a better method.

Here is the function I have problems with:

> Prove that
> $$f(x) = (1-\cos x)\sin\frac1x$$
> is equally continuous in the section $(0, \infty)$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The "better method" being others to solve it for you, obviously. With that "method", you won't solve any non-trivial problem yourself, ever.

Comment: @ProfessorVector you said this is what I was looking for. I didn't say that.
yes, I wanted a solution for this specific problem, but I am also looking for it to have some explanation of who is solve such problems generally (as I stated in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using the facts that $\frac {1-\cos x} {x^{2}} \to \frac1  2$ and $|\sin (\frac 1 x)| \leq \frac 1 {|x|}$ show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x\to 0+$. Also, using boubndedness of $1-\cos x$ show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x\to \infty$. These two facts and continuity of $f$ yield uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

$$-(1-\cos x)\le  (1-\cos x)\sin(1/x) \le (1-\cos x)$$
Then by sandwich theorem
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1-\cos x) \sin(1/x)=0$$
As $\lim_{x \to 0} \pm (1-\cos x)=0$
Further,  $f(x)$ being finite in $(0,\infty)$, it is continuos everywhere